# In PHP, how can I specify that a search with parameters only takes them from the current category

Tags: php, search, parameters, categories

I have a functioning search that works with parameters, for example brand or price, on a site that has top and sub categories. Now, when I am within a sub-category, and enter parameters, it gives results from the top category, not just the sub. I'm looking for a way to specify, to make it only look in the current category.

```
 var searchParam = {};
  <?php if (isset($_GET['q'])): ?>
    searchParam['q'] = '<?php echo $_GET['q']; ?>';
  <?php endif;?>
  <?php if (isset($category)): ?>
    searchParam['cat'] = '<?php echo $currentcategory; ?>';
  <?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Please add the data arrays (or tables) to the question.

Comment: How do you know you are "within a sub-category"?

Comment: I may be mistaken here but this would also need some source modifying on the php side.

Comment: Julio: By being within the category on the website. Ie you click on coponents-brakes-brake pads: youre in the subsub category brake pads, but the search will return everything from components.

Comment: @MelanieRittinger, quick tip. Use `@` infront of peoples names so they get notified when you post a reaction.